# Can Hecke Operators be defined on more general spaces of elliptic curves?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Classically, the Hecke Operators act as endomorphisms of $\omega^k_{\mathcal{M}_{ell}(\mathbb{C})}$, defined by noting that there is a distinguished class of covering maps $\widetilde{E}\to E$ given by noting that $E=\mathbb{C}/\Lambda$, and $\Lambda$ has a finite number of sub-lattices of degree $n$. We have that the $\widetilde{E}$ are elliptic curve, so summing over the form on these curves, we obtain the Hecke Operators. My question is whether this can be extended to more general varieties?

For example, let $X$ be a smooth complex variety. An elliptic curve $E\to X$ one should have that etale covers $\widetilde{E}\to E\to X$ of degree $n$ have $\widetilde{E}$ elliptic, so we should be able to sum over some space of etale covers, but I don't know enough about how to make this work.

Comment: Have you looked at the 'obvious' (not obvious from the perspective of 'you should have known that', obvious from the perspective of 'natural to the experts') extension of modular forms? I'm speaking, of course, of Shimura varieties. More importantly than *how* you obtain such maps (which is what your post is focusing on) is the general focus on the types of objects that have a 'Hecke action'. Namely, if $G$ is any group over $\mathbb{Q}$ (let say affine and connected) then you might define a space with a '$G$-Hecke action' to be a projective system of varieties $\{X_U\}$

Comment: where $U$ ranges over the open compact subgroups of $G(\mathbb{A}^\infty)$ satisfying some obvious conditions (e.g. $U\subseteq U'$ 'sufficiently small' implies that $X_{U'}\to X_U$ is a finite étale cover with Galois group $U/U'$, etc. etc. One then obtains a Hecke action via the nartual correspondences $X_U\leftarrow X_{gUg^{-1}\cap U}\to X_U$. Or, more naturally, the cohomology of the projective system (i.e. $\varinjlim H^i(X_U,\mathcal{F})$ or $H^i(\varprojlim X_U,\mathcal{F})$) has an honest-to-god action by $G(\mathbb{A}^\infty)$ called the Hecke action. Is this the sort of thing

Comment: that you were looking for? Of course, your example of the Hecke action on modular forms is such an example of this with $G=\text{GL}_2$.

Comment: @AlexYoucis If I'm honest, I don't know! :) I don't know a decent amount of the notation! Though this definitely sounds like what I was looking for! Is there a good introductory reference on this type of stuff? Googling Hecke Actions seems to lead to a combination of seemly techincal papers and volleyball.

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. Milne's book on the subject of Shimura Varieties is good, but it doesn't really get to the heart of the matter in the way that you want. A good place to see this stuff in action (although a little steep for the feint of heart) are Kottwitz's papers and some papers of Harris. The real issue is that to work with these things one must first understand Shimura varieties (the generalization to many $G$ of the case of $\text{GL}_2$-Shimura varieties=modular curves). Do you have something specific in mind that you want to know?

Comment: @AlexYoucis No, but Milne's introduction read very well, and contains a huge number of citations. Thank you!